# User creation with PHP : disable sending email

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

I'm using the User Class to create new users. Here are my fields :

```
$udata = array(
                "name"=>$data['name'],
                "username"=>$data['user'],
                "password"=>$data['pass'],
                "email"=>$data['email'],
                "block"=>0,
                "groups"=>array("1","2"),
                "params"=>array(
                    "admin_style" => "",
                    "admin_language" => "",
                    "language" => 'fr-FR',
                    "editor" => "",
                    "helpsite" => "",
                    "timezone" => ""

                ),
                "requireReset"=>1,
                "sendEmail"=>0,
            );
```

I put sendEmail to 0 but the email is still sent. Is there an other way to disable this function?

Thanks for your anwser !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sendEmail` property relates to whether or not the user should receive system emails, rather than whether or not a confirmation email should be sent upon user creation.

I had a quick look through the code and the confirmation email seems to be sent from the `User - Joomla!` plugin, in the `onUserAfterSave` function. There it checks the param `mail_to_user` before deciding whether to send or not.

This parameter is set within the options for the `User - Joomla!` plugin. Click on Plugins, and then on the User - Joomla! plugin and set `Notification Mail to User` to No

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Unfortunatly, it doesn't work when I insert in params array. Is there a way to create plugin onUserAfterSave that will replace the original? If I create it, the original onUserAfterSave is still firing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried it out. I've corrected the answer, and confirmed it works ok.